# Git Hist Alias Problems

Tags: git

I'm working through the gitimmersion and creating alias [plural]. Everything worked except my hist.

```
$ git config --global alias.hist log --pretty=format: '%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short
```

this takes me to the .config page, but doesn't create an alias

I know the code works (the part that I am making an alias for) because when I run

```
$ git log --pretty=format: '%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short
```

it does the task I want.

Any ideas for making the alias work

Answer (score 6):

You need some `""` there to get everything passed through properly:

```
git config --global alias.hist "log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short"
```

In addition, I think you have an extra space between `format:` and the format string in both of your examples.

Comment: Where is your second "" ?  If I type what you have it asks for more code with >

Comment: There is one before `log` and one at the end of the line.  I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: I receive an error when I run $ git hist   |||returns |||                                 fatal: ambiguous argument '': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

Comment: That's because of your extra space, as already mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

you've missed off '--add' and git doesn't like the space between `format: '%h` (at least on my mac)

try:

```
$ git config --global --add alias.hist "log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short"
```

Comment: this one worked on win10 for me as well...  thanks guys.